# pass data message to div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass a data-message to a div, here is the current setup:

html

```
<a data-message="my message" href="www.site.com">Click here</a>

<div class="new-window" style="display: none;">
    <p>(message should be here)</p>
</div>
```

js

```
$('a[data-message]').click(function(){
    $('.new-window').fadeIn(300).text($('.new-window p').data('message'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It works in a JS Fiddle so something else must be wrong.

Comment: I am in jquery mobile.. not seeing it?

Comment: Refer to my answer, you were trying to pull data-message from a place where it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$('a[data-message]').click(function(){

    var message = $(this).data('message');
    $('.new-window').fadeIn(300)
                    .find('p')
                    .text( message );

    return false;
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/cMkKY/

Answer (score 2):

`$('.new-window p').data('message')` as this will not have the data-* attributes. so its not returning anything.

change like this

```
   $('a[data-message]').click(function(){
    var values=$(this).data('message');
    $('.new-window p').text(values);
    $('.new-window').fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: you should `find` the `p` before setting the text as that is where the text should go(*as per the OP*)

Comment: If I use (this) then how do I pass it to the <p> tag?

Answer (score 0):

After the call to fade-in replace with 
.text($(this).attr('data-message'));
Or
.text($(this).data('message'));

You want to pull the value from the anchor's attribute, not the target div.

Comment: either use the `-` as in `data-message` or use the `data()` method `.data('message')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

html

```
<a data-message="my message" href="www.site.com">Click here</a>

<div class="new-window" style="display: none;">
    <p>(message should be here)</p>
</div>
```

js

```
$('a[data-message]').click(function(){
    $('.new-window').fadeIn(300).text($('a[data-message]').data('message'));
    return false;
});
```

Further Explanation:
You were referring to data-message in .new-window p, a place where it doesn't exist.